# Git LFS: How to make .gitattributes catch multiple extension-less files with the same name, but in different folders, without files with extension

Tags: git, git-lfs, gitattributes

I'm trying to set up the .gitattributes for Git LFS to catch all extension-less files with a certain name. They are scattered out across different folders. And I don't want it to catch those with same name, but with an extension.
Example:

```
A/B/C/D/Foo
A/B/C/D/Foo.meta
A/B/C/D/E/Foo
A/B/C/D/E/Foo.meta
A/B/F/Foo
A/B/F/Foo.meta
```

The three Foo files should be catched, but the three Foo.meta-files shouldn't.

More files of this kind might occur in automatically generated folders throughout production. So hardcoding the paths is not ideal.

I've tried adding the following to my .gitattributes:

```
Foo diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

That almost works, but also catches the Foo.meta-files. The following is not allowed because “Negative patterns are ignored in git attributes”:

```
Foo diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
!.meta diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, I will note that `Foo` by itself will not match `Foo.meta` (I have tested this to be sure, although in a slightly stale Git, 2.27.0).  You must be using something like `Foo*` as in my example below.

Although *negative* patterns are forbidden in `.gitattributes`, *positive* patterns do everything you need:

```
Foo*    attr1=value1 attr2=value2
*.meta  !attr1
```

This makes use of the paragraph that is near the front of [the gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes):

> Sometimes you would need to override a setting of an attribute for a
> path to `Unspecified` state. This can be done by listing the name of the
> attribute prefixed with an exclamation point `!`.

Note the earlier paragraph that says:

> When more than one pattern matches the path, a later line overrides
> an earlier line. This overriding is done per attribute.

Here, all files whose name begins with `Foo` take on `attr1=value1`, but then all files whose name ends with `.meta` remove `attr1` entirely.  All files whose name begins with `Foo` also take on `attr2=value2`; the second line leaves that in effect since it does not explicitly clear `attr2`.  Should you wish to do so, it's trivial to add `!attr2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! You got me on the right track - as you can see below! Also, I learned a lot from your post - I didn't know that you could use positive patterns like this. I'll bookmark this question, as it sure could come in handy later, as a part of my git toolbox. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @torek - you got me on the right track!

Turned out, that the problem was about how I tested the .gitattributes! Because I didn't want the big files to end up on git by accident, I ran the following command to test what would happen:

```
git lfs status
```

But it wasn't showing correct results! It showed the `Foo.meta`-file under as "`Git LFS objects to be pushed to origin/master:`". But when I actually pushed, non of the .meta-files went to Git LFS (only the extensionless files did).

So all is good - except why git lfs status didn't gave the correct results. But that's for another question, I guess.